# How can i pass a GET parameter to a POST form

Tags: php, html

sorry if the title is a little unclear I'm not sure how to properly word it.

But basically my question boils down to this: I have a page where i can post a new blog post to my database this works fine, but I also want this same page to have the ability to edit existing blog posts.

The way I do this is: i have a dropdown select where i loop through all of the posts in my database if i select a post my URL will change to this `http://localhost/blabla/BlogPost.php?blogid=133` this is fine as well, but when i click on my save changes button which is in a form that uses the POST method. Obviously the GET parameter is lost and it doesn't save the changes.

// this is where i check if the blogid isset and which button to show

```
            if (!isset($_GET["blogid"])){
            ?>
            <button name="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Opslaan</button>
        </form>
        <?php
        } elseif (isset($_GET["blogid"])) {
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="BlogBE.php">
                <button name="submitBtnEdit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Wijziging opslaan</button>
            </form>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

// This is the script which checks which button got clicked

```
if (isset($_POST["submitBtnEdit"])) {
        try {
            $blogid = $_GET["blogid"];
            // save file as binary base64 data in database
            $uploadFile = $upload->save();

            // initialize new connection
            $db = new Connection();

            // open connection
            $database = $db->openConnection();

            // prepare query
            $stm = $database->prepare("UPDATE `blog` SET `title` = :title, `content` = :content, `author` = :author, `img` = :img WHERE blog.blogid = $blogid");

            $text = $_POST["editor1"];

            // bind parameters for query
            $stm->bindParam("title", $_POST["title"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm->bindParam("content", $_POST["editor1"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm->bindParam("author", $_POST["author"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm->bindParam("img", $uploadFile, PDO::PARAM_STR);


            // execute query
            $database->beginTransaction();

            $result = $stm->execute();

            $database->commit();

            if ($result === TRUE) {
                echo sprintf("Successfully posted");
                $db->closeConnection();
            } else {
                echo sprintf("Something went wrong");
            }
        } catch (InvalidFilenameException $e) {
            echo sprintf("Invalid filename" . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidExtensionException $e) {
            echo sprintf("Invalid extension" . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (FileTooLargeException $e) {
            echo sprintf("File is to large" . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (UploadCancelledException $e) {
            echo sprintf("upload is cancelled" . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (Error $e) {
            echo sprintf("Something went wrong" . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (InputNotFoundException $e) {
            echo sprintf("Input not found" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So my question is how do i keep the GET parameter in a POST form

Comment: Pass the `$_GET` variable in a [hidden html field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp). Should be noted that you need to clean the `$_GET` before adding it as a hidden html element, or else you will open yourself up for XSS

Comment: you can check any data with `$_REQUEST['']`